# git init re-creates .git file in home directory

Tags: github, git-init

I want to keep a separate work space for my development job.I moved .git file from my home directory to another directory named 'workspace'. Now when I use `git init` in `workspace` directory, everything works just fine but when I use `git init` inside my home directory, it re-creates the `.git` file in my home directory.
I am using Ubuntu and my home directory is `home/tyler`.This is where `.git` file is stored my default.

My directory structure is:
home/tyler
home/workspace

Comment: Don't just move the `.git` file, move the entire folder and children.  An acceptable solution for you might be to just `git clone` what you need at home.  Let Git do the work for you.

Comment: I can see only `.git` folder there.What do you mean by it's children??Please clarify!

Comment: I'm suggesting that you just go home and clone the repositories that you need.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you just go home and clone the repositories that you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to clone your git workspace.

Go in your new folder where you want the copy of your repo and execute `git clone [folder to your repo]`
that will create a folder inside that with the name of your repo folder.

Hope that helps